# How to include source of external library for IntelliSense in a CMake project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, intellisense

I am working on a C++ application in Visual Studio, using the Visual Studio's CMake project template.
To build my application I only need the header and the external library and I can link it like this:

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for myapp, include source and define project specific logic here.

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (myapp "myapp.cpp" "myapp.h")

# Add TIFF library
set(TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR "C:\\libs\\tiff\\out\\install\\x64-Debug\\include")
set(TIFF_LIBRARY "C:\\libs\\tiff\\out\\install\\x64-Debug\\lib\\tiffd.lib")
find_package(TIFF REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE TIFF::TIFF)
```

So far, so good. I can use the tiff library to open, read, write tiff files, etc., and IntelliSense is catching up with declarations in the header files. But, I would like IntelliSense to also be aware of the full source code of the TIFF library. For example, if I am in myapp.cpp and I `ctrl+click` on `TIFFOpen` it opens the header corresponding to `TIFFOpen`, but when I `ctrl+click` `TIFFOpen` in the header file, it doesn't go to the corresponding source file, which is the normal behaviour for source files in `myapp`. This is understandable, since I never told Visual Studio where to find the source files of the external library.

CMake doesn't need to know where the source files of the external libraries are, since it won't build the external library, therefore I guess I don't/shouldn't change anything in CMakeLists.txt

One option (I haven't tried yet, but I'm fairly sure it would work), would be to just include the entire tiff library as a sub-project of myapp. I do have some problems with this solution though:

1. The external library is not conceptually an integral part of the project, and I don't plan to modify the external library. This is more of a principle issue.
2. Simply having it as a subfolder in my project makes it a risk of changing something I didn't intend to change.
3. I don't want to rebuild the external library when I do a rebuild all. I know Visual Studio / CMake is smart enough to figure out that nothing changed and doesn't rebuild, but I would rather have Visual Studio / CMake not even try.

The way I see it, I have to set the directory with the source files somewhere in Visual Studio settings, but still related to the project. My best guess is that the `.vs/ProjectSettings.json` is the file I need to edit somehow, but honestly, I have no clue.

Alternatively, maybe I could write some command in `CMakeLists.txt` that doesn't do anything, but triggers the IntelliSense to look in the folder with source files. Again, I have no clue how should I go about this.

In a nutshell, I want IntelliSense to see all source files of an external library, the same way it sees the source files of myapp, without including all source files of the external library as a sub-project of myapp. How should I go about it, if even possible?

If relevant, I use Visual Studio 2019 Community and the CMake it comes with it (3.15).

Comment: First, you don't need to manually set TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR and TIFF_LIBRARY, as find_package and target_link_libraries set up everything and those variables are never needed. Second, cmake has a target property called "exclude from all", which guarantees the target to never be built, you might include tiff project and set it to that, however this does violate your intention to not include it as subproject at all.

Comment: @X.Sun I also thought that ```find_package()``` would at least try to search through my files to find that package, but it doesn't. Without setting ```TIFF_``` variables, I get this error ```Could NOT find TIFF (missing: TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR)```. Ultimately I am happier this way, because various apps on my pc have some version of the TIFF library, and I prefer to use a specific one that I personally indicate. The "exclude from all" property seems like a fair compromise. I hope for a better solution, but if all else fails..

Comment: In that case you might need to check the tiff library you installed has complete cmake exported files such as TIFFConfig.cmake and TIFFConfigVersion.cmake in its instllation folder, and they can be found through system's Path variable (Clearly you are using windows so it should be set manually after installation). Modern cmake only requires find_package and target_link_libraries. Also cmake files are case sensitive, Tiff and TIFF are different. But frankly, a lot of libraries haven't switched to modern cmake yet and don't have proper exports, even some fundamental ones.

Comment: I also noticed you added "tiffd.lib", which means always use the debug build of tiff library. A proper cmake setup would switch between "tiff.lib" and "tiffd.lib" according to your build configuration, just a hint in case you run into other problems when building release binaries.

Comment: @X.Sun Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me out. I just downloaded the official latest version, opened it with VS, then Build, then Install, and no TIFFConfig.cmake or TIFFConfigVersion.cmake was created anywhere, but I guess libtiff-4.pc might be the TIFFConfigVersion.cmake file

Comment: Hi, does the build successfully or not? Most of the time, if the build succeeds but instllisense throws errors, that's one issue in Intellisense. But if the build and Intellisense all throw errors, maybe that format is not supported.

Comment: I'm currently using Git submodules and building as part of the project, but would like to find a hybrid solution as well, where I have access to sources for quick look up but link against binaries, if available. In my case I would go a step further and build from sources if I detect changes in the Git submodule with `git describe` dirty flag.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your last comment, writing code in comment section is inconvenient so I'll just post it here although not an answer.

`libtiff-4.pc` is for pkg-config, not cmake, and `find_package()` can't deal with it directly on Windows and would take some work if you really want to. It might be easier to just write everything manually. Remember to set the `tiff.lib` and `tiffd.lib` according to your configuration. You can use `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable and `if()` command such as:

```
# set build type to release if not specified
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE OR CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "")
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release" CACHE STRING "Build Type" FORCE)
endif()
# switch lib to link according to build type
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")
    # for release
    set(TIFF_LIBRARY "<your_path_to_installed_lib>/tiff.lib")
else()
    # for debug. If you have other configs like relwithdebinfo you can add more
    set(TIFF_LIBRARY "<your_path_to_installed_lib>/tiffd.lib")
endif()
```

Also, remove `find_package()` and use `target_link_libraries()` and `target_inlude_directories()`:

```
set(TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR "<your_path_to_installed_headers>/include")
target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE ${TIFF_LIBRARY})
target_include_directories(myapp PRIVATE ${TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

You can also skip setting `TIFF_LIBRARY` and `TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR` and pass the string directly if you like.

I use Visual Studio a lot and it's my favorite IDE. But package management with cmake on Windows is not as smooth as Linux. Always remember to set environment variables after compiling and installing external libraries.

Normally find_package() will look for a system environment variable named `<libname>_DIR` (for example `TIFF_DIR`, which is not found in your case), which is used to store path to installed lib, then look for `<libname>Config.cmake` and `<libname>ConfigVersion.cmake` in that folder (and would fail for `TIFF` since it doesn't have them).

It also searches other places, check https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/find_package.html?highlight=find_package for details.

So for those libs with cmake exported files, add a variable with correct name and value. And that's only for compiling.

If you want your application to run after compiling, you also need to add the path of installed lib's binaries (usually *.dll) to system's `Path` variable. In your case you should find something like `tiff.dll` and `tiffd.dll` after compiling and installation, add that folder to `Path` and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. Just to make clear, with the configuration laid out in the question, it already works to use the TIFF library (with the mention that indeed I'm strictly linking to the debug version, and I should change that, as you suggested). My main issue is just that intellisense only go as far as the headers. Considering this, I foresee troubles when myapp will grow and I'll need more serious debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, showing the source in the IDE is easy enough.

Just add the source with `add_library(tiff_for_ide EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ${SOURCES})` but don't link with it in the main program. You'll want to use a different target name for the library. For this you'd need the source in your project directly or as a submodule (if using Git, something else if available by you VCS).

Other options are using `ExternalModule_Add`; or `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` with the `add_library` as above, to avoid adding third party deps into the repository directly.

Now, just cross your fingers and hope that the IDE is not intelligent enough to restrict searching for sources that are linked against the target which compiles the current file. Or that it's intelligent enough to detect this situation but fallback to searching the whole project files anyway when it's linking against a binary.